# How to Remove label on pie chart

Tags: java, android

I have Created Pie Chart using PhilJay MPAndroidChart but i do not want Text and figure written on pie chart it should be beside of pie chart with color an description with figure. now it display at downside without figure. [image]

Comment: How u resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 8):

To remove x-Values use `pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false)`.

To remove y-Values use `pieChart.getData().setDrawValues(false)`.

Answer (score 2):

pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false) has been deprecated so use pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false) instead